# UWP query.GetItemCountAsync - Fails on mapped network drives. 'The library, drive, or media pool is empty. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710D2)'

Tags: uwp, enumerate

If I enumerate a mapped network drive using the code below, while it takes ages and consumes 5 GB memory, it gets the job done, no errors.

```
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

If I use the query system to get the number of files, which works perfectly on a local disk, it fails on the same network mapped drive.

```
var fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByTitle, fileTypeFilter);
var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var x2 = await query.GetItemCountAsync();
```

The error is "System.Exception: 'The library, drive, or media pool is empty. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710D2)'" - which isn't useful at all. Yes I've looked this up on google and get a huge, 5 results.

Any thoughts on why this is happening ? Maybe because the local drive is indexed and the network not, but then that makes this query pointless anywhere as you can't guarantee a folder is indexed.

Comment: Hello, I tried to use the provided code to get the number of sub-files of the folder in the mapped network drive, and the normal result can be returned. You can check whether the folder in the drive is correctly connected to the specified location.

Comment: The drive is a permanently mapped NAS (Synology) drive over WiFi on Windows 10 2020H2. MY code in Win32 works perfectly locally and on the mapped drives. UWP GetFiles works perfectly, only GetItemCount fails, and only on the mapped drive.

Comment: Indexing isn't the problem as you can't index mapped drives, and I know the drive is online and responding because I can view it using Windows Explorer.

Comment: Hello, as you said, this may require a special reproduction environment. Do you accept the use of Win32 API in UWP to achieve your goals?

Comment: I've evaluating exactly that scenario, performance, memory usage, disk/network usage for different scenarios. UWP with GetFiles, Get Count and iterate, Win32 allowed API. I was hoping not to use the Win32 API, but it looks like a must :( - and then there's the massive memory leak in the StorageFile class :( - let me clarify that, UWP cannot recover the memory used in storing StorageFile objects when no longer used.

Comment: Hello, `StorageFile` is a file object and can be explicitly set to null if it is not needed. C#'s garbage collection mechanism periodically cleans up unreferenced objects. If you are reading the content of the file through `Stream`, please call `Stream.Dispose()` method or use the `using()` statement to release the stream after the content is read.

Comment: I have to disagree about the GC cleaning it up. This simple example shows my problem: var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName); it populates "files", however, set files = null; no garbage collection, go through each object in files and set them to null; no garbage collection. If "files" is a global varaible in the app, the GC will never release the memory (it's actually the Runtime Broker that consumes the memory).

Comment: Hello, GC does not happen instantaneously, it will periodically check the reference status of the object. If files is used as a global variable, then its reference always exists. You can manually call `GC.Collect()` to force GC

Comment: Manually calling the GC does not recover the memory. If I use the code in a method, so the scope of 'files' is that method only, even after calling the GC never recovers the memory. I called the GC, and waited 10 minutes, nothing. I think the problem is that the "App" is actually consuming very little memory, it's the Runtime Broker that's holding it as a separate process, and the GC has no control over that. I seem to remember some "rarely used" attribute for a method to force memory to be returned, but I can't find anything on that so can't test.

Comment: Hello, generally speaking, the inability to reclaim memory by calling GC indicates that the object is still in a reference state, but this may be another problem. Have you obtained the files in the mapped network drive through win32 api?

Comment: The files obtained are local using StorageFolder.GetFiles. As I said, when using this, the app itself does not consume much memory at all, and all looks well, but when you look at the attached Runtime Broker, that consumes 5 GB memory, it only releases it when the app closes, or if I do method calls where the GetFiles and resultant  StorageFiles are only ever used within the same method. If they're used anywhere else, like a global variable or returned from the call, the Runtime Broker never gives up the memory - this includes me setting each to null, erasing any list they were in.

Comment: Hello, Runtime Broker is equivalent to a common bottom layer, and its memory usage does not represent the memory usage of the current application. If you think this is a problem, you can provide feedback in the Feedback Hub app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was actually documented, but the error was not.

The original question was on why I sometimes get an error using:

```
var fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByTitle, fileTypeFilter);
var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var x2 = await query.GetItemCountAsync();
```

The answer is in the use of "CommonFileQuery.OrderByTitle", it doesn't work on network drives. It has to be replaced with "CommonFileQuery.OrderByName" and then it works.

Of course, performance is still dire, and the Runtime Broker memory consumption is appalling. I don't agree that consuming 5GB memory and not releasing it, is acceptable. That basically stops me using the new WinRT StorageFile/Folder, even in Win32 app on .net 5.

But the question is answered; let's hope .net 6 and WinRT can fix this :)